# High school magnetic flux physics question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

[image: Physics flux question]

Hi can some one help me understand why the answer to this question is C. Also why is a current or emf created in this situation when you move a conductor in a B field? I thought that there is no change in flux, its simply moving in a fairly uniform magnetic field.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by: "there is no change in flux". Through what **area** are you checking the flux?

Comment: This situation may be easier to understand in terms of "motional EMF";  is that something that you've seen in your class?

Comment: @npojo wait is the wire experiencing a change in flux because part of the loop is being lifted so the area of the wire loop is increasing - .hence change in flux?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert no i dont think we have.

Comment: @user341191 - yes.

Answer (score 2):

The flux is the constant $\vec{B}$ field times the effective area of the loop, where by "effective" I mean the projection of the area in the (signed) plane normal to $\vec{B}$--and *that* changes.

Step 1 is establish the direction of $\vec{B}$ in drawing: It is south-to-north, which would be "into" the drawing.

The next step is to figure out when the effective area is changing the fastest. This occurs at "A" and "C". At "B" ("D") the area is maximal (minimal)-- which is where it's stationary, i.e., changing the least.

Step 3 is figuring out the sign of the effect so that current is flowing from "P" to "Q". You can use the formula, or appeal to Lenz's Law.

Lenz's Law states the current will flow to maintain the flux. Since the projected area is decreasing at "C", you need a current that adds flux "into" the drawing. A quick check of the right-handed rule should convince you that this occurs when current flows from "P" to "Q"--which is the desired result. Hence *C*: "C" is correct.